# Is developing an android/phonegap app with Netbeans IDE a good method?

Tags: android, eclipse, netbeans, cordova

My objective is to have an IDE with JS syntax error reporting and a PhoneGap plugin.
My goal is to make an android application using PhoneGap.

I understand that Eclipse has a well supported PhoneGap plugin.
The issue is that I have spent hours trying to get Eclipse JS syntax error reporting to work with no luck.

Netbeans is extremely easy to install and has working JS syntax error reporting with no extra steps needed. For example, with NetBeans, I just install and everything (including JS syntax error reporting) works. With Eclipse, I must install, then install several addons related to JS. In the end, I could not get the JS syntax error reporting of Eclipse to work, despite hours of research. I am new to Eclipse.

Is developing an android/phonegap app with Netbeans IDE a good method?
I found this plugin, but don't know exactly how it works with PhoneGap or if it's any good: http://www.nbandroid.org/

Comment: have you see this ? http://nebulousweb.com/2013/03/developing-a-phonegap-android-app-using-netbeans/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Phonegap plugin described [here](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/34483744/PhoneGap-Eclipse-PlugIn-for-Android) on the PhoneGap wiki includes the default Eclipse JSDT syntax checking. It also includes an option to turn on customizable JSLint checking - see Section 7 [here](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/startdetails). This all comes with a single plug-in to add the Android ADT.

If something's not working for you, it would be great if you raised the specific problem on StackOverflow, on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/eclipse-plugin-for-phonegap), or create an [issue](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/issues/list).

Comment: Thanks for the good advice. I was able to install Eclipse Class, SDK Starter Package, ADT plugin and PhoneGap plugin. It worked! I documented it here: https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1qs5YO8fX0nPL3CVNlsS-PqfgYlIQSvqGIRbNmCJMLpY

Answer (score 0):

From 7.4 version Netbeans has Phonegap support without external modules.
Obviously you need also phonegap and android sdk :)
see http://wiki.netbeans.org/MobileBrowsers#PhoneGap_2